# Create bytearray from string in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, byte

Let's say I want to create a bytearray from a string. For example, a string like this:

```
"90, -123, 38, 0, 0, 3, 118, 93, 283, -1"
```

How would I do this in Kotlin?

Comment: `.toByteArray()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this perhaps:

```
val split = "90, -123, 38, 0, 0, 3, 118, 93, 122, -1".split(',')
val result = ByteArray(split.size){ split[it].trim().toByte() }
```

Note: 283 is outside the range for Byte.

Comment: You could avoid one temporary list by combining the two `map()` calls: `.map{ it.trim().toByte() }`.  And you could avoid both temporary lists (at the expense of slightly more complex code) by storing the results of the `split()`, and then creating the ByteArray directly from that, e.g. `ByteArray(split.size){ split[it].trim().toByte() }`.